# Does $\max\{x|h_n(x) = 0\} \to \max\{x|h(x) = 0\}$ provided $h_n$ is continuous, convex and $h_n \to h$ uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

> Let $\beta = \max\{x|h(x) = 0\}, \beta_n = \max\{x|h_n(x) = 0\}.$ Assume that $\beta,\beta_n$ exist and finite. If $h_n \to h$ uniformly and $h_n, h$ are continuous, convex. Does it imply that $\beta_n \to \beta$?

I dont know whether or not it is true. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

If it is not true, what sort of condition to make it happen?

Comment: no. consider $h_n(x):=\frac{1}{n}$ for $0<x<1$ and $h_n$ linearly growing such that $h_n{'}(x)=1$ for $x<0$ or $x>1$. then $\beta_n<0$ and $\beta=1$.

Comment: @Max thank you, what if $h_n, h$ are convex?

Comment: also negative: consider $h_n^{'}=-1$ for $x<0$, $h_n(0)=0$, $h_n^{'}(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ for $0<x<1$, $h_n^{'}(x)=1$ for $x>1$. then, $\beta=1$ and $\beta_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: i think what you need is an environment $U$ around $\beta$ such that for $x\in U, x>\beta$ we have that $h(x)>0$ and for $x\in U, x<\beta$ we have that $h(x)<0$ (or the other way around).